# What does appStateManager.addListener(notifyListeners); mean?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following raywenderlich's flutter apprentice tutorial (Chapter 7 https://www.raywenderlich.com/books/flutter-apprentice/v1.0/chapters/7-routes-navigation)
and I am not able to understand what the call to addListener(notifyListener) means in the following code. Specifically, I am thinking that addListener should be taking in a Listener object but here, it is taking a function which is defined in the super class!

```
class AppRouter extends RouterDelegate
    with ChangeNotifier, PopNavigatorRouterDelegateMixin {
 
  // 3
  final AppStateManager appStateManager;
  // 4
  final GroceryManager groceryManager;
  final ProfileManager profileManager;

  AppRouter({
    required this.appStateManager,
    required this.groceryManager,
    required this.profileManager,
  }) : navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>() {
    appStateManager.addListener(notifyListeners); 
    groceryManager.addListener(notifyListeners);
    profileManager.addListener(notifyListeners);
  }
...
}
```

Any idea what is going on and how it is working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, the `addListener` functions adds a listener, that triggers the functions that's provided. So essentially, every time the `XXXStateManager` state changes, it will trigger the `notifyListeners` method from the `ChangeNotifier` class

Comment: So basically, anyone listening to AppRouter , will be notified of changes in XXXStateManager? IOW, any changes to XXStateManagers will automatically be notified to all listeners of AppRouter.
Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: yes, if i understand you correctly, you are right